# Python for loop in data loading

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am looking at this timeseries prediction [example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/dlmacedo/starter-academic/blob/master/content/courses/deeplearning/notebooks/pytorch/Time_Series_Prediction_with_LSTM_Using_PyTorch.ipynb?pli=1#scrollTo=vIWvJCpOVmwU)

In dataloading section there is a forloop which i am unsure if it has a purpose

```
    x =[]
    y =[]

    for i in range(len(_data)-seq_length-1):
        _x = _data[i:(i+seq_length)]
        _y = _data[i+seq_length]
        x.append(_x)
        y.append(_y)
    return x,y
```

Is someone able to explain it's purpose ?

Comment: This splits the data into chunks of length `seq_length` into a list of lists as opposed to having a single list with all the data in it. E.g. instead of loading `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, you would load `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]` given `seq_length = 2`.